# Using a variable in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the src of an image file. Tried the below using with the variable, but it actually doesnt change it. Where did I made a mistake on using variable ?

jquery

```
var p2begen = "416";
$("[id=i'" + p2begen + "']").attr("src", "check.png");
```

html

```
<img src="nocheck.png" id="i416" \>
```

Comment: you are forgetting the `#` in `$("[id=#i'" + p2begen + "']")`

Comment: With this code you are modifying id `i'416'`, remove those '. Also, as answered by others, the correct way to select ID is with # `$('#element_id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reference an id in jquery you need to add the `#`. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in the jquery docs. It is important to note that ids must be unique, but you can use a class on as many elements as you like.

```
var p2begen = "416";
$("#i" + p2begen).attr("src", "check.png");
```

If you wish to use classes instead your code should look like this:

```
<img src="nocheck.png" class="i416" \>

var p2begen = "416";
$(".i" + p2begen).attr("src", "check.png");
```

Comment: its an `id` not a `class`.

Comment: Here is the deal, I want this applied on all the divs that has the same id. So will that do this ?

Comment: You can only have one id... if you want to reference numerous elements by the same name you need to use a `class` name and then use `.` as opposed to `#`. there is a description here - http://ryanfait.com/articles/the-difference-between-ids-and-classes/

Comment: Does the solution work if you change it to use a class?

Answer (score 1):

add the `#` at the start.

```
var p2begen = "416";
$("#i" + p2begen).attr("src", "check.png");
```

if you want to stick with the attribute selector, use:-

```
var p2begen = "416";
$("[id='#i" + p2begen + "']").attr("src", "check.png");
```

by adding the `#` and moving the `'` back 2 places.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for doing that is to use selector for ids, and your selector will looks like this:

```
var p2begen = "416";
$('#i' + p2begen).attr("src", "check.png");
```